# Find and simplify $a^3+c^3-b^3c\pmod{19}$ when $a \equiv 2\pmod {19},b \equiv 4\pmod {19}, c \equiv 5\pmod {19}$

Tags: number-theory

Suppose $a \equiv 2\pmod {19},b \equiv 4\pmod {19}, c \equiv 5\pmod {19}$. Find and simplify $a^3+c^3-b^3c\pmod{19}$

My attempt

$a^3+c^3-b^3c\pmod{19}=2^3+5^3-(4^3*5)\pmod{19}=8+125-320\pmod{19}=8+125-16=117$

Am I on the right track?

Comment: now you probably want to reduce modulo $19$.

Comment: @Lubin, I thought I already reduced it to modulo 19 as  $320 \pmod {19}=16$. Do you mind clarifying a bit? My discrete math book does not have a great chapter on modular arithmetic and going off of online resources. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I meant for you to reduce $117$ modulo $19$.

Comment: I thought I already reduced $a^3,c^3$. For example a=2(mod 19), so $a^3=2^3$. I did the same for $c^3$. I think I am missing some other important concept.

Comment: Well, since $117\equiv3\pmod{19}$, the final answer I’d have been looking for is $3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is correct, but the notation is a bit redundant. In one line, you can have $$\begin{align}a^3+c^3-b^3c&\equiv2^3+5^3-4^3(5)\equiv8+125-320\equiv-187\equiv3\pmod{19}\end{align}$$

Comment: I see what you mean. You are saying that the question should be written as $(a^3+c^3-b^3c)mod 19$.

Comment: The point is that when you’re working modulo $19$, there are only $19$ different values, each of them represented by infinitely many integers. Conventionally, we choose the one among these integers that’s between $0$ and $18$, though in answering “$117$”, you told no lie.